# Python - Using RegEx to extract only the String in between pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to parse log file to figure out how many users are logging into the system on a per-day basis.

The log file gets generated in the pattern listed below.

"<"Commit ts="20141001114139" client="ABCREX/John Doe">
"8764","ABCREX/John Doe","00.000.0.000","User 'ABCREX/John Doe' successfully logged in from address '00.000.0.000'."
"<"/Commit>
"<"Commit ts="20141001114139" client="ABCREX/John Doe">
"8764","ABCREX/Jerry Doe","00.000.0.000","User 'ABCREX/Jerry Doe' successfully logged in from address '00.000.0.000'."
"<"/Commit>
"<"Commit ts="20141001114139" client="ABCREX/John Doe">
"8764","ABCREX/Jane Doe","00.000.0.000","User 'ABCREX/Jane Doe' successfully logged in from address '00.000.0.000'."
"<"/Commit>

I am trying to capture the username from the above lines and load into DB.

so I am interested only in values

John Doe, Jerry Doe, Jane Doe

but the when I do pattern match using REGEX it returns the below

client="ABCREX/John Doe">

then using the code I am employing I have to apply multiple replace to remove
 "Client", "ABCREX/", ">"...etc

I currently have code which is working but I feel its highly inefficient and resource consuming. I am performing split on  tags then parsing reading line by line.

'''extract the user login Name'''
UserLoginName = str(re.search('client=(.*)>',items).group()).replace('ABCREX/', '').replace('client="','').replace('">', '')

print(UserLoginName)

Is there any way I can tell the REGEX to grab only the string found within the pattern and not include the pattern in the results as well?

Answer (score 0):

pattern = r'User\s\'ABCREX/(.*?)\''

list_of_usernames = re.findall(pattern, output)

That would match the pattern
"User 'ABCREX/Jerry Doe'" and pull out the username and add it to a list. Is that helpful? I'm new here too so let me know if there is more I can help answer.